# How to replace question mark from a String so that same letter does not occur next to each other?

Tags: algorithm

I wrote the code below to replace each question mark from a String so that same letter does not occur next to each other. For example:

Input

```
ab?ac?
```

Output

```
abcaca
```

Please note that `?` should be replaced by any lowercase letter: `[a-z]`

Below is my solution. But my question: is there any more optimized way to solve this?

```
public String solution(String riddle) {
    char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    if (riddle == null || riddle.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        return riddle;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < riddle.length(); i++) {
        char current = riddle.charAt(i);
        char prev = '\0';
        char next = '\0';
        if (current == '?') {
            current = alpha[cnt];
            if (i != 0) {
                prev = sb.toString().charAt(i - 1);
            }
            if (i != riddle.length() - 1) {
                next = riddle.charAt(i + 1);
            }
            while (current == prev || current == next) {
                current = alpha[++cnt];
                if (cnt % 25 == 0) {
                    cnt = 0;
                }
            }
            sb.append(current);
        } else {
            sb.append(current);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It is already `O(n)` I don't think it is possible to make it better than that.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your algorithm degrades to *O(n²)* because of this conversion to string:

```
prev = sb.toString().charAt(i - 1);
```

This `.toString` call needs time linear to the current length of `sb`. And this is really unnecessary, as `.charAt` is also available on a `StringBuilder` instance. So the quick fix is to do:

```
prev = sb.charAt(i - 1);
```

Now the code will run with *O(n)* time complexity, and that cannot be improved further.

However, you can still gain some time using the following observations:

- There is no need to pick up `prev` with `charAt`, since you could just do a `prev = current` assignment at the end of each iteration (and change its scope accordingly).
- There is no need to look into 26 alternative letters for a `?`. Every question mark can become either `a`, `b` or `c`. No other letters are needed -- you just need three (any three distinct letters would work). So there is no need to have `alpha`, no need to have `cnt`, and no need to apply a remainder operator to it. A simple ternary expression can do the job.
- You can avoid code repetition and move the `append` call out of the `if...else` blocks.

So here is how the code could look:

```
public String solution(String riddle) {
    if (riddle == null || riddle.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        return riddle;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    char prev = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < riddle.length(); i++) {
        char current = riddle.charAt(i);
        if (current == '?') {
            char next = '\0';
            if (i != riddle.length() - 1) {
                next = riddle.charAt(i + 1);
            }
            current = prev != 'a' && next != 'a' ? 'a'
                    : prev != 'b' && next != 'b' ? 'b'
                    : 'c';
        }
        sb.append(current);
        prev = current;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution in Java 8 for all input scenarios.

```
public String solution(String input) {

    StringBuilder riddle = new StringBuilder(input); // convert string to string builder

    // handling when string is empty
    if (riddle.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    // handling when there is only one character in the string
    if (riddle.length() == 1) {
        if (riddle.charAt(0) == '?') {
            return "a";
        } else {
            return riddle.toString();
        }
    }

    int count = 97;

    // running loop for input string whose length is more than 1
    for (int i = 0; i < riddle.length(); i++) {

        // handle the character at 0 index
        if (i == 0 && riddle.charAt(i) == '?') {
            riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) count);
            if (riddle.charAt(i) == riddle.charAt(i + 1)) {
                riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) (count + 1));
            }
        }

        count = 97;

        // handle the character between 0 and last index
        if (i != 0 && riddle.charAt(i) == '?' && i != riddle.length() - 1) {
            
            riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) count);
            
            while (count >= 97 && count <= 122) {
                if (riddle.charAt(i) == riddle.charAt(i + 1) || riddle.charAt(i) == riddle.charAt(i - 1)) {
                    riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) count);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        count = 97;

        // handle the last character in the string
        if (i > 0 && i == riddle.length() - 1 && riddle.charAt(i) == '?') {

            riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) count);

            while (count >= 97 && count <= 122) {
                if (count == riddle.charAt(i - 1)) {
                    count++;
                    riddle.setCharAt(i, (char) count);

                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    return riddle.toString();

}
```