# Remove/Replace question mark with characters to make string lexicographically smallest

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, replace

I am trying to solve a different version of the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293130/how-to-replace-question-mark-from-a-string-so-that-same-letter-does-not-occur-ne) which is much more interesting but highly difficult to be done as I am not able to crack what is the pattern needed to solve it.

- Given a string containing question marks and alphabet characters (for ease assume they are either ALL UPPERCASE or all lowercase)
- All '?' needs to be replaced with characters **(or completely removed) <- new thing to original problem** satisfying the condition no adjacent characters are same
- The final string **should also satisfy the condition of being lexicographically** smallest **<-new condition than original**

I am able to do the original replacement problem completely but need some input for this one.
Example:

Input1: `B?AC`
Output1: `BAC`

Input2: `B??AC`
Output2: `BABAC`

Answer (score 0):

First, all else being equal, shorter comes first.  So strip all `?` from the end of the string.

After that just work left to right, replacing `?` in a way that moves the earliest letter first.  Using `A`, `B` and `?` to be themselves, and `C` to be any other letter or the beginning of the string, every remaining `?` can be removed with these rules.

```
A?? -> AB?
A?A -> ABA
A?B -> AB
B?? -> BA?
B?A -> BA
B?B -> BAB
B?C -> BAC
C?? -> CA?
C?A -> CA
C?B -> CAB
C?C -> CAC
```

Comment: What is meant by saying moves the earliest letter first?

Comment: @Mathpdegeek497 I mean try to make the first letter in the alphabet that can appear at that position, appear.  See the set of substitutions and verify that that is what I described.

Comment: Then how will you proceed with B??AC 
Won't this logic fail here?